# Round down float using bit operations in C

Tags: c, floating-point, bit-manipulation

I am trying to round down a float using bit operations in C. 
I start by converting the float to an unsigned int. 
I think my strategy should be to get the exponent, and then zero out the bits after that, but I'm not sure how to code that. This is what I have so far:

```
float roundDown(float f);
unsigned int notRounded = *(unsigned int *)&f;
unsigned int copy = notRounded;
int exponent = (copy >> 23) & 0xff;
int fractional = 127 + 23 - exponent;
if(fractional > 0){
   //not sure how to zero out the bits. 
   //Also don't know how to deal with the signed part.
```

Comment: floorf(), roundf() and  related functions do this.  Is this homework?  It does not seem overly practical to me.

Comment: No, not homework, I am trying to learn bitwise operations in C and this is an exercise in a textbook. I have been struggling with it for several hours, it would be nice if I could get it working.

Comment: You may need to zero out all, some or none of the mantissa bits, depending on the value of the exponent.  Have you looked at e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision, which shows you the structure of a float?  Also, do you mean "round toward zero", or "round towards -infinity"?

Comment: seems like a lousy book, better to teach useful info. normally you just use a function and do not do bit fiddling when you don´t have to.

Comment: Thanks Oli, but I have seen that page. I understand the structure of a float, consisting of the signed bit, the exponent, and the mantessa. I don't know how to zero out bits.

Comment: I think it's round toward 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`float roundDown(float f);` should be `float roundDown(float f) {`.

`unsigned int notRounded = *(unsigned int *)&f;` is incompatible with modern compiler optimizations. Look up “[strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)”.

Here is a working function to round down to the power of two:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

float roundDown(float f) {
  unsigned int notRounded;
  assert(sizeof(int) == sizeof(float));
  memcpy(&notRounded, &f, sizeof(int));

  // zero out the significand (mantissa):
  unsigned int rounded = notRounded & 0xFF800000; 

  float r;
  memcpy(&r, &rounded, sizeof(int));
  return r;
}

int main()
{
  printf("%f %f\n", 1.33, roundDown(1.33));
  printf("%f %f\n", 3.0, roundDown(3.0));
}
```

This should produce :

```
1.330000 1.000000
3.000000 2.000000
```

Comment: Why do we take 4 bits from the fraction? (& 0xFFF8 , first 9 is sign and exponent)

Comment: @dexter4712345 There was a typo (now fixed). It was still working because I had counted the zeroes, not the ones (there was the correct number of zeroes; I had written `0xFFF800000`. The computation was done with 64-bit integers because this constant could not be represented on 32-bit, but it worked).

Comment: Thanks, this has been very helpful. I see now that the main operation is the bitwise &. How can I modify to deal with negative numbers? For example, how can I round -1.5 down to -2?

Comment: @user2057841 Rounding negative numbers down to the power of two towards -inf is really more complicated. You have to make a special case for numbers that already have a 0 significand (return the same number without change), and for the others, add one to the exponent. Adding one to the exponent can be done while manipulating the integer representation with `+ 0x00800000`, I think.

Comment: @Pascal  notRounded & 0xFF800000 , yeah that makes much more sense.

Comment: How can I check if the number has a 0 significand? Would 1<<notRounded work?

Comment: @user2057841 The significand is zero if `(notRounded & 0x007FFFFF) == 0`

Comment: Hi thanks again for your help. I am still trying to get it working for negative numbers and such, to make sure I understand. I am trying to zero out the bottom digits from the unsigned short. Since I need to zero out a different number of bits everytime, how can I do this? I need to zero out the bottom 23-exponent bits, but how can I make a mask that will work for a different exponent each time?

Answer (score 1):

Since its just for fun, and I'm not sure what the constraints are, here's a variant that DOES work for negative numbers:

```
float myRoundDown_1 (float v) {        //only works right for positive numbers
    return ((v-0.5f)+(1<<23)) - (1<<23);
}

float myRoundDown_2 (float v) {        //works for all numbers
    static union {
        unsigned long i;
        float f;
    } myfloat;
    unsigned long n;
    myfloat.f = v;
    n = myfloat.i & 0x80000000;
    myfloat.i &= 0x7fffffff;
    myfloat.f = myRoundDown_1(myfloat.f+(n>>31));
    myfloat.i |= n;
    return myfloat.f;
}
```